# how to enable/disable buttons based on cookies

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have created buttons known as **set cookie** , and **delete cookie**. now i have a requirement of **enabling set cookie** button and **disable delete cookie** button when a **cookie is not set**, and also to **disable the set cookie button** and **enable the delete cookie button** when a **cookie is set**. following is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
setcookie("name", "John", time()+3600, "/","", 0);
setcookie("age", "36", time()+3600, "/", "",  0);
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>WCSST 2</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type='text/css'>
</style>
</head>
<body>

      <?php
        if(!isset($_COOKIE["name"])) {
        echo "cookie not set";
        }else
        echo $_COOKIE["name"];
      ?>
        <button style="color: black"><b>Set Cookie</b></button>

        <button style="color: black"><b>Delete Cookie</b></button>

<!-- END PAGE SOURCE -->
</body>
</html>
```

can anybody help on fullfilling the above requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code

```
 <button style="color: black" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])) { ?> Disabled <?php } ?> value='Set Cookie'>

 <button style="color: black" <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE["name"])) { ?> Disabled <?php } ?> value='Delete Cookie'>
```